# Gradle sets absolute paths to Maven repository in org.eclipse.wst.common.component

Tags: eclipse-wtp, gradle-eclipse

Given a gradle build script with plugins `war`, `maven` and `eclipse-wtp`.

`gradle eclipseWtp` make entries in `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` with absolute paths that cannot be committed to the source code repository, since they are user specific - see the `<dependent-module>` elements, more specifically the `handle` attributes:

```
[...]
<dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/classpath/lib/C:/Users/mp/.m2/repository/ognl/ognl/3.0.6/ognl-3.0.6.jar">
    <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
<dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/classpath/lib/C:/Users/mp/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar">
    <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
<dependent-module deploy-path="/WEB-INF/lib" handle="module:/classpath/lib/C:/Users/mp/.gradle/caches/artifacts-24/filestore/org.springframework/spring-context-support/3.2.4.RELEASE/jar/bcb2341e76ef4621f2422b1f066fb34c42fad08d/spring-context-support-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar">
    <dependency-type>uses</dependency-type>
</dependent-module>
[...]
```

How can Gradle come up with more commit-friendly paths, e.g. by using M2_REPO variables?

Comment: Is there any special reason to check-in generated files because I am sure you know that every user could just generate them executing `gradle eclipse`?

Comment: Only reason is to avoid steps where possible. Any step that needs to be taken per user is a step that can be forgotten to be taken by the user.

Comment: Ok, I see your reason. So check my answer below, which should solve your problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Gradle documentation (see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html) you can specify path variables:

```
eclipse {
  // if you want parts of paths in resulting file to be replaced by variables (files):
  pathVariables 'M2_REPO': file('C:/Users/mp/.m2/repository')
}
```

The variable has to be set within Eclipse via "Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables' and works for `.classpath` as well as `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component`

Comment: Did you tried this? For me it works only in case of .classpath but org.eclipse.wst.common.component still contains absolute pathes...